# Uncaught error when trying to create a service ngmodule

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a servicesModule which will contain all the services.
The first service I'm trying to move is my remote service, but I'm getting this error, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'RemoteService' declared by the module 'ServicesModule'
```

The RemoteService is as simple as it get

```
import {Injectable, OpaqueToken} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class RemoteService {
    constructor() {
        console.log("RemoteService created");
    }
}
```

and the service module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RemoteService } from "./remote.service";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [RemoteService],
})
export class ServicesModule { }
```

And finally the app component

```
import { ServicesModule, RemoteService } from "./services";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ServicesModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    RemoteService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `providers` to declare your module services :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RemoteService } from "./remote.service";

@NgModule({
    providers: [RemoteService]
})
export class ServicesModule { }
```

Comment: Notice I edited the code to include RemoteService in the app.module (removed it by mistake when I copied the code into the question). 
Thank you @ranakrunal9, that works.